# Chunking SQL statements in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, python-itertools, cartodb

I'm working on trying to use existing PostGIS code with CartoDB. [I have created a Python script](https://gist.github.com/laidig/9eec4331addf35904ca0) to take in data, chunk it, and POST to CartoDB , but the setup files include multi-line create statements that don't chunk well. So I find myself submitting very large chunks.

[The set of queries](https://github.com/laidig/gtfs_SQL_importer/blob/master/src/gtfs_tables.sql) I'm trying to submit in the URL via POST is around 9000 bytes, after which I get a 414 (too large) error.

Does anyone have an idea of how to constrain the chunks to be complete statements (e.g. terminated by a ;)?

```
def grouper(iterable, n):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
       chunk = tuple(islice(it, n))
       if not chunk:
           return
       yield chunk

buffer = []

#pattern to match blank or comment lines
pattern = re.compile("^\s*\-\-.*$|\s+$")

for line in fileinput.input():
    #drop blank or comment lines.
    if pattern.match(line):
        pass
    else:
        buffer.append(line.strip())

for group in grouper(buffer,500):
    query = "".join(group)

    params = {
        'api_key' : config['apikey'],
        'q'       : query
    }
    r = requests.post(API_URL, params=params)
```

Comment: What happens if you post every time your next line is a create table?  DDL commands like create table tend to emit an implicit commit anyway so you can create what you've read, insert and then commit. Repeat on next create insert chunk. Your queries listed are < 9k in your examples.